# Maven dependency with reusable build goals

Tags: java, maven, build, parent-pom

I'm working on a Java SDK. The project's build tool is Maven. The SDK provides classes (helpers) to write code for an API. It also provides a build configuration which makes it possible to build the application in a specific way (native image).

To use the build configuration from the SDK I (think I) need to package it as a `pom`, and then use it as a parent. However, to use all the SDK classes, I need to package it as a `jar`.

Is it possible to use a Maven dependency is the above described way? Or maybe I actually need two projects, one for just the SDK, and the other one which would provide the build configuration?

Comment: There are missing a lot of details ... what exaclty is the problem? Why have to set your packaging to pom ? Why really necessary as parent?

Comment: Problem/question is stated in "Is it possible to use a Maven dependency is the above described way?" i.e. is it possible to import a dependency's build configuration as well as the dependency's classes.

Comment: The answer to " Why have to set your packaging to pom ?" is "To use the build configuration from the SDK I (think I) need to package it as a `pom`"

Comment: The build configuration from the SDK ? How is that defined ? Is that part of a plugin configuration or via properties in your pom file? Do you use a java agent or alike? Generally you can define an sdk in a dependency but the question is what is needed to configure things for a native image.. than things like configuration for the native build needed which sounds like a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix the two aspects.

To provide a dependency, you build a JAR.

To provide build configuration, you can provide a parent POM. Beware, though, that many people already use parent POMs and you cannot have two parent POMs at the same time. So it might be better to provide an XML snippet to copy&paste into the POM.

Comment: I was having a feeling that's the answer.:) Plan B for me was actually that what you mentioned, but I was trying to find a more automatic way.